# Generate a CSV file for Excel with Symfony

Tags: symfony

after hours of research I can't find the solution, I want to display the content of $results in an excel file I tried to do that in the download function but I can't add the table data result in the variable $myvariableCSV. i hope it's clear

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller\MissingPDV;

use App\Entity\Upload;
use App\Form\UploadType;
use App\Repository\UploadRepository;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Box\Spout\Reader\Common\Creator\ReaderEntityFactory;

/**
 * @Route("/upload")
 */
class UploadController extends AbstractController
{



    /**
     * @Route("/new", name="app_upload_new", methods={"GET", "POST"})
     */
    public function new(Request $request): Response
    {
        $upload = new Upload();
        $form = $this->createForm(UploadType::class, $upload);


        $form->handleRequest($request);
        $results=[];
        $cells1=[];
        $cells2=[];
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

            //add date information
            $upload->setDate(new \DateTime('now'));

            $NamesOfFiles=[];
            // adding File1
            $file1= $form->get('file1')->getData();
            $NamesOfFiles[]=$file1->getClientOriginalName();
            $fileName1 =md5(uniqid()).'.csv';
            $file1->move($this->getParameter('upload_directory'),$fileName1);
            $upload->setFile1($fileName1);

            // adding File 2
            $file2= $form->get('file2')->getData();
            $NamesOfFiles[]=$file2->getClientOriginalName();
            $fileName2 =md5(uniqid()).'.csv';
            $file2->move($this->getParameter('upload_directory'),$fileName2);
            $upload->setFile2($fileName2);

             // Adding text 1 fields
            $text1= $form->get('text1')->getData();
            $upload->setText1($text1);

            // Adding text 2 fields
            $text2= $form->get('text2')->getData();
            $upload->setText2($text2);

            // Read first File and find column according to text (Spout)

            $filePath= dirname(__DIR__).'/../../public/uploads/'.$fileName1;

            $reader = ReaderEntityFactory::createCSVReader();

            $reader->open($filePath);

            foreach ($reader->getSheetIterator() as $sheet) {

                foreach ($sheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {
                    // do stuff with the row
                    $cells1[] = $row->getCells();

               }
            }
            $reader->close();

            //Reading File2 wth spout Library Reader

            $filePath2= dirname(__DIR__).'/../../public/uploads/'.$fileName2;

           $reader2 = ReaderEntityFactory::createCSVReader();

          $reader2->open($filePath2);

          foreach ($reader2->getSheetIterator() as $sheet) {
             foreach ($sheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {
                  $cells2[] = $row->getCells();

                }
            }

          $reader2->close();


        // put in array File 1 element
            $goodcolonne='';
            foreach ($cells1[0] as $colonne=>$nom){
                if ($nom == $text1){
                    $goodcolonne = $colonne;
                    break;
                }
            }

        $basepdv=[];
            for ($i=1;$i<count($cells1);$i++){
                $basepdv[]=$cells1[$i][$goodcolonne];
            }

        // put in array File 2 element

        foreach ($cells2[0] as $colonne=>$nom){
            if ($nom == $text2){
                $goodcolonne = $colonne;
                break;
            }
        }
        $newpdv=[];
        for ($i=1;$i<count($cells2);$i++){
            $newpdv[]=$cells2[$i][$goodcolonne];
        }

      // comparer et sortir les pdv manquants

        foreach ($newpdv as $pdv){

            if(!in_array($pdv,$basepdv)){
                $results[]=$pdv;
            }
        }

            return $this->render('vuejs/resultat.html.twig',[
                'resultats' => $results,
                'namesOfFiles' => $NamesOfFiles,
            ]);
        }

        // ici on charge le formulaire vide
        return $this->renderForm('upload/new.html.twig', [
            'upload' => $upload,
            'form' => $form,
        ]);
    }


    /**
     * @Route("/download", name="download")
     */
    public function download($results)
    {
        //Nom des colonnes en première lignes
        // le \n à la fin permets de faire un saut de ligne, super important en CSV
        // le point virgule sépare les données en colonnes
        $myVariableCSV = "code_pdv;\n";
        //Ajout de données (avec le . devant pour ajouter les données à la variable existante)
        $myVariableCSV .= ;\n;
        //On donne la variable en string à la response, nous définissons le code HTTP à 200
        return new Response(
            $myVariableCSV,
            200,
            [
                //Définit le contenu de la requête en tant que fichier Excel
                'Content-Type' => 'application/vnd.ms-excel',
                //On indique que le fichier sera en attachment donc ouverture de boite de téléchargement ainsi que le nom du fichier
                "Content-disposition" => "attachment; filename= PDV_manquants.csv"
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

i try to do download fonction it's works when i add some string variables but i want do add results

Answer (score 0):

If you use EasyAdmin you can export your data easily by "goodby-csv" composer. Please take a look at this link:

https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/easyadminbundle/global-action

Comment: Link only answers are very much frowned upon and there is no indication that I can see that the question involves easy admin.  It is pretty trivial to download a csv file regardless.  Plenty of similar questions out there. The posted code is not comprehensible to me I'm not going to try and generate a useful answer.

Comment: thank you lubna for your help i appreciate i read this https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/easyadminbundle/global-action but i don't know how to use it .instead of this can you please tell me how i can fetch this missing_pdv file in my  download function?